# Store website cookies in Android Webview forever

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I want to store my website cookies permanently in my Android Webview APk so that a user don't have to enter login details every time he starts the app. Please tell me in details as I am beginner. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you. Please take a look (you may **copy/paste** the code too)

```
public class MessangerMainFragment extends Fragment{
    WebView telegram_web;

public MessangerMainFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messanger_main, container, false);
    setupUI(v);
    init();
    return v;
}

public void init() {
    telegram_web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    telegram_web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    telegram_web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    telegram_web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    telegram_web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    telegram_web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
        }
    });

    telegram_web.loadUrl("https://web.telegram.org/#/im");

}

public void setupUI(View v) {
    telegram_web = v.findViewById(R.id.telegram_web);
    if (!UniversalUtility.isOnline(getContext()))
        UniversalUtility.handleFailureResponse("t.getMessage()", "messanger");

}

public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getContext());
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().stopSync();
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could you please tell me the only code lines which saves the cookies? It will help me a lot.

Comment: CookieSyncManager Lines are mandatory...(in onCreate, onPause,  onResume and in Client - OnPageFinished)

And below codes are also mandatory...

    
 
 
 
 telegram_web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
     telegram_web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);